# Another simple Thetaseries identity.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, theta-functions

Let $\vartheta(z)=\sum_{n\in Z}e^{\pi \mathrm{i}n^2z}$ I want to show that
$$(\vartheta\left(\frac{z}{4}\right)-\vartheta(z))=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}e^{\pi\mathrm{i}(n+1/2)^2z}$$ After using the hint.

\begin{align*} 
\vartheta\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)&=\sqrt{\frac{z}{i}}\left(\vartheta\left(\frac{z}{4}\right)-\vartheta(z)\right)=\sqrt{\frac{z}{i}}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}e^{\pi\mathrm{i}(2n)^2(z/4)}+e^{\pi \mathrm{i}(2n+1)^2(z/4)}-e^{\pi \mathrm{i}n^2z}\\&=\sqrt{\frac{z}{i}}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}e^{\pi \mathrm{i}n^2z+\pi \mathrm{i}nz+\pi \mathrm{i}(z/4)}=\sqrt{\frac{z}{i}}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}e^{\pi\mathrm{i}(n+1/2)^2z}.
\end{align*}

Comment: you just asked almost the same question : $\vartheta(z) - \vartheta(4z) = \sum_n e^{i \pi n^2 z} - \sum_n e^{i \pi (2n)^2 z}= ...$

Comment: $\theta(x/4)-\theta(x)$ reminds me of an interesting paper: Riemann’s Zeta Function-The alternating Xi-Function $\xi_a()$ by Malderen at arXiv: 1610.04344 [math.NT].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

Write $$\Theta(z/4)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\left( e^{i\pi (2n)^2(z/4)}+e^{i(2n+1)^2(z/4)}\right)$$in terms of even and odd terms.

Comment: guess who upvoted

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you!  Much appreciated.  -Mark